# How the OS handles python and subprocesses of a python script...?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, subprocess, sh

My question is somewhat unique. I am currently working on a project for my computer forensics class. This project is aimed at hiding disk data from investigators. The method by which this is supposed to be achieved is by writing the bytes of a "clean" file over the "bad" file. Once overwritten, the "bad" file is deleted.

This concept sounds simple enough, but what my partner and I have observed is interesting. If we open a file in a python script, we can easily overwrite the memory associated with that file on disk (verified using dd). We can also easily delete a file using from inside the script. However, a write then delete results in no write actually taking place, only the file's removal.

This makes sense from an OS optimization standpoint. From that point, we thought it might work if we split the writing and deleting into two separate scripts, and controlled both by a third. However, it seems that even if we run the scripts as a subprocess of another script, the same thing happens. We've tried to use bash scripts for the deletion process instead of pure python, and still, nothing sticks.

This project was supposed to be a whole mess of little anti-forensics tools like this, but this particular one has captured our whole attention because of this issue. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening and what we can do to move forward?

We know this can be achieved in C, etc, but we want to solve this using python because of the interesting constraints it's presented.

---EDIT---
This is a snippet from our controller, it calls "ghost.py" with the associated params.

ghost.py prints the edited file names/paths to stdout.

Relevant code follows:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ghost.py', '-c', 'good.txt', '-d','/mnt/evil.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
files = proc.communicate()

for i in files:
    if i != None and i != "\n":
        os.system("./del.sh " + i)
```

Comment: try `file_handle.flush()` after the write or just `file_handle.close()` which should also flush the file to disk

Comment: we are currently using `f.close()` with no luck. But, I'll be off to give flush a shot.

Comment: How are you launching the children from the parent? (In particular, are you inheriting file descriptors, as you do with `os.system`, and which is the default with `subprocess` in Python 2.7 and 3.1, but not in 3.2+; are you creating a new session; etc.)? That may affect whether the OS optimization can take place…

Comment: Also, have you considered using an unbuffered `file`/`io.*` object, going straight to `os.open`/`os.write`, and maybe using `O_DIRECT` and `O_SYNC`? (If you do _all_ of those, it includes the effects of the `f.flush()` automatically, of course…) I don't know which of those will affect what you're seeing, but I think learning the answer to that might be helpful to you on its own…

Comment: we have tried using `os.system` and `subprocess` both, also making sure to include `sys.exit()` at the end of the write script to ensure that process completes.

Comment: @stackunderflow: You didn't answer my question. _How_ are you using `subprocess`? Are you inheriting file descriptors, creating  a new session, etc.?

Comment: It would really help if you posted the code that demonstrates the problem. It's really hard figuring out what you're doing and what's going on as a result from descriptions.

Comment: i posted a code snippet for those asking.

Comment: what happens if you open / *read* the overwritten file before deleting it?  I know, it's a bit of lame question after everyone's suggestions, but will the OS optimize by going back to some caching that's sticking around or will it go to file?

Comment: thats what ghost.py does. it opens the "bad" file for writing, and read n bytes of the "good" file. It then writes those bytes to the "bad" file before closing both. ghost.py prints the list of the changed files to stdout to be read into the delete shell script.

Comment: no, i meant: close bad file after overwriting.  then reopen it before deletion.  end of the day, from the point of the os, you could be considered not to be using the changed file contents before deletion, so they hardly matter.  which is what you said already, i know.  just wondering if a read-before-delete changes things.  could this be a file system artifact, i dunno, like a journaled file system caching the update until such a time as it is ready to write?

Answer (score 1):

Using a subprocess doesn't change any interesting aspect of your design, so don't use them. You probably need `os.fsync()`. Try this pattern:

```
myfile.write('all of my good data')
myfile.flush()
os.fsync(myfile.fileno())
myfile.close()
os.remove(myfile)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync